# Print list using for loop

Tags: loops, python-2.7

I want to create a list that outputs something like this:

1. string1
2. string2
3. string3
4. string4

but the number at the beginning to be a number that is a variable that incrementally increases by one in the loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the index in Python for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
for i, s in enumerate( ("string1", "string2", "string3"), start = 1 ):
    print "{}. {}".format( i, s )
```